# C program to output characters produces integers instead

Tags: c, stdout, stdin, stderr

I'm writing a program called **split.c** that takes from the **stdin** an **input.txt** file as input and then sends every other word within the input file to **stdout** and **stderr**.

My current codes is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  int input;

  // keep getting characters until end-of-file
  while ((input = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF){

  // prints to stdout
  fprintf(stdout, "%d", input);
  if(input == " ")
      printf("\n");   // encounters whitespace so print new line

  // prints to stderr
  fprintf(stderr, "%d", input);
  if(input == " ")
      printf("\n");   // encounters whitespace so print new line

  }

  return 0;

}
```

In ubuntu I run `make` then the command `./split < test/input.txt > myout.txt 2> myerr.txt`

The expected output should be, for example.

If **input.txt** has the following: `"Is my code working?"`

The output should be:

In `myout.txt`:

```
"Is
code
```

In `myerr.txt`:

```
my
working?"
```

Instead I get the following in both files, a huge number:

```
6511032731101001051181051001179710...............
```

Any idea was to what may be wrong with the code?  Is my thought process wrong?  The idea is that it gets the input file, reads each character and then, when a whitespace is found, it prints a new line in **stdout**, then does the same thing, but now printing to **stderr** until it reaches EOF.

I'm still learning the in's and out's (pun intended :) ) of using **stdin/out/err** so I'm not surprised if I'm not coding correctly.  Any guidance is appreciated!

Comment: As rlee827 notes, the numbers are coming from `%d`.  Also `input == " "` needs to be `input == ' '`.  Also you're printing everything to both stdout and stderr; you haven't really got code yet to do the alternation properly.  You probably want to have an outer loop containing two inner loops: the first inner loop would read and copy to stdout until it finds a space, and then the second one would do the same for stderr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `%d` specifier that interprets the corresponding argument as a number. You should be using `%c` to interpret the corresponding argument as a character.

Comment: Though if you are just printing a single character and nothing else, you probably want to use `putc` instead of `fprintf(..., "%c",...)` as it is simpler and more efficient.